# JavaScript - Create and Edit .xls or .xlsx (Excel Spreadsheet) Files WITH OFFICE JS API

Tags: javascript, excel, api

I saw that Microsoft made an Office API for JavaScript.
I've seen that it's possible to use their API to develope add-ins for some of the Office softwares.

But does anyone know if it's possible to use it, or a different API of theirs, to create, read and write Excel .xlsx or xls files? I don't care what type to use.

I'm basically running a script that would create data that I want to put into excel, and want to not lose the data, so I could run the script, stop it, and continue it so it'd continue writing the data from where I left off.

I want it to be as fastest as possible. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, and don't have a lot of experience it as a developer (I just didn't work with it much, although I did learn it and know how program in it).
I also want for the development to be as quick as possible.
I don't mind spending time on learning how to use different libraries, but if it's possible, I prefer to do it as little as possible.

So I want something simple and fast, and I don't want a lot of special options. All I care about is writing the data.

The script itself will do:

*Data analysis

*Data output into a JS file

And I want continue the script so it'd continue filling in data into the created file.

That's all there's to it.

I prefer to use something official from Microsoft, because it'd probably the best solution for that.
If such tools/libraries/API(s) don't exist, or if there are better solutions, what do you recommend?

Comment: Are you going to be using `node.js`? There are a few packages that allow for easy interaction with .xls files ([xlsjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsjs)), and there are a few out there specifically for .xlsx but they are slightly unstable

Comment: I edited my original post with information on what I want the script to do, and my preferences about the technology/ies I prefer to use.

If you don't mind, I'd love for you to read my preferences and tell me if and how xlsjs would fit.

Comment: There are a lot of samples you can use to see what you would like to do: https://github.com/OfficeDev?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=excel To get started with Excel Add-ins, see http://dev.office.com/excel/add-ins. I hope this helps!